# Select left 10 numbers, left join for a price from second table, and then sum, SQL

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2012, sum, multiplication

I am currently working in sql 2012 visual management studio. I have two tables. Table1 has three columns (ItemNumber as varchar, Quantity as int, and TimeOrdered as datetime). Table2 has 2 columns (ItemNumber as varchar, and Price as float). Please note these item numbers are not the same, the part numbers on table 1 have a letter after the number while the table 2 item number does not. For example on table 1 the item number will look something like this 999999999-E and the other table will just be 999999999-. Therefore I must use a select Left for 10 digits to get the part number.

I need to pull a list of item numbers from table 1 based on the time ordered and then cross compare that list to table 2 and multiple the price times the quantity for a grand total. Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT sum(tbl.quantity * table2.price) as grandtotal,
       tbl.PartNumber,
       tbl.quanity,
       table2.price
FROM
   (SELECT left(itemnumber, 10) as itemnumber, quantity 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE TimeOrdered between 
                            ('2014-05-05 00:00:00.000')
                      AND 
                            ('2015-05-05 00:00:00.000')) as tbl 
Left table2 on
tbl.partnumber =tbl2.itemnumber
```

I am receiving an error here for aggregate columns but I am not sure this is the correct way to go about this to begin with.

-------------update---------------

I got it working. Sorry for taking so long to get back to you guys, I was stuck in a meeting all day,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How About This. The case is just to avoid div by Zero errors.

```
SELECT sum( Isnull(tbl.quantity,0) * Isnull(table2.price,0) ) as grandtotal,
tbl.PartNumber,
Sum(tbl.quanity),
case when Isnull(Sum(tbl.quanity),0) = 0 then null else 
      sum(Isnull(tbl.quantity,0) * Isnull(table2.price,0) ) / Sum(tbl.quanity) end 
as Price
FROM
(SELECT left(itemnumber, 10) as itemnumber, quantity FROM table1 WHERE TimeOrdered between 
('2014-05-05 00:00:00.000')
AND ('2015-05-05 00:00:00.000')) as tbl 
Left outer join table2 on
tbl.partnumber =tbl2.itemnumber
group by tbl.PartNumber
```

Comment: give me a moment while i try this.

Comment: I got this to work and I have the grand total column. Now how could I sum the grand total column without doing an excel spreadsheet and manually adding them.

Comment: SELECT Sum(grandtotal ) from (
--Write the Above Query here
) a

Comment: The grandtotal in the SELECT Sum statement is not recognizing the column name.

Comment: you sure this works at my place
SELECT Sum(grandtotal ) from (

SELECT sum( Isnull(tbl.quantity,0) * Isnull(table2.price,0) ) as grandtotal,
tbl.PartNumber,
Sum(tbl.quanity),
case when Isnull(Sum(tbl.quanity),0) = 0 then null else 
      sum(Isnull(tbl.quantity,0) * Isnull(table2.price,0) ) / Sum(tbl.quanity) end 
as Price
FROM
(SELECT left(itemnumber, 10) as itemnumber, quantity FROM table1 WHERE TimeOrdered between 
('2014-05-05 00:00:00.000')
AND ('2015-05-05 00:00:00.000')) as tbl 
Left outer join table2 on
tbl.partnumber =tbl2.itemnumber
group by tbl.PartNumber

) a

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77209/discussion-between-abdul-rehman-sayed-and-cheddar).

Answer (score 0):

SQL server requires you to explicitly `group by` the columns you're not aggregating by. So you need to add `group by tbl.PartNumber, tbl.quantity, table2.price`. Of course, that's *probably* going to make the `tbl.quantity * table2.price` kind of useless. What are you actually trying to do? :)

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/99171/1)**

```
 SELECT SUM(t1.quantity * t2.price) AS 'GrandTotal'
    ,SUM(t1.quantity) AS 'Quantity'
    ,t1.itemnumber
    ,t2.price
 FROM Table1 t1
 JOIN Table2 t2 ON LEFT(t1.itemnumber, 10) = t2.itemnumber 
 WHERE t1.Timeordered BETWEEN '2014-05-05 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-05-05 00:00:00.000'
 GROUP BY t1.itemnumber, t2.price
```

Comment: give me a moment while I try this

Comment: All of my column selection above table1 t1 can not be bound. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72bbd/14) is a fiddle with some sample data that should give you what you want. You need to include any non-aggregate columns in your group by.

Your code ends up as follows:

```
SELECT left(table1.ItemNumber, 10) as PartNumber,
       table2.price,
       sum(table1.quantity) as totalquantity,
       sum(table1.quantity * table2.price) as grandtotal
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON left(table1.ItemNumber, 10) = table2.ItemNumber
WHERE t1.Timerordered BETWEEN '2014-05-05 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-05-05 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY table1.ItemNumber, table2.price
```